# python code running and then shows code error -1

Tags: python

```
total_cost = float(input("enter the cost of house:  "))

#down payment is 25% of actual cost
portion_down_payment = (0.25) * total_cost
current_savings = 0
annual_salary = float(input("enter your annual salary: "))
#monthy saving from salary is 10%
portion_saved = (0.1 )* (annual_salary / 12)
#rate investment r(annual)is 4% of savings
rate = (0.04 / 12)   
months = 0
#calculating months it will take you to save up enough money for a down payment

while current_savings != portion_down_payment:
    current_savings = current_savings + portion_saved + (current_savings * rate)
    months = months + 1
    print(current_savings)

print("no.of months needed to save for down payment: ", months)
```

The code is running and showing `inf` as current savings and no, of months goes to around 1 million. It never exits while loop !

I entered  total cost =100,000,000
   and annual salary =1,000,000

Comment: Please consider fixing your indentation. And you try to check if it is equal what you probably want to know if the current savings are still to small for the down payment so replace `!=` with  `<`

Answer (score 3):

Do not use use `!=` or `==` to check for float.

Instead use `<` instead for your context to indicate that you haven't gathered enough fund.

```
while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
```

Modified code:

```
total_cost = float(input("enter the cost of house:  "))

#down payment is 25% of actual cost
portion_down_payment = (0.25) * total_cost
current_savings = 0
annual_salary = float(input("enter your annual salary: "))
#monthy saving from salary is 10%
portion_saved = (0.1 )* (annual_salary / 12)
#rate investment r(annual)is 4% of savings
rate = (0.04 / 12)   
months = 0
#calculating months it will take you to save up enough money for a down payment

while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    current_savings = current_savings + portion_saved + (current_savings * rate)
    months = months + 1
    print(current_savings)

print("no.of months needed to save for down payment: ", months)
```

Answer (score 3):

Think about what you wrote there: you only exit your loop when the down payment is *exactly equal* to the current savings. This makes little sense. You should put `<` instead. As soon as the savings are *at least the same* as the down payment can you exit the loop.

While it is true that you shouldn't compare rounded floats with `==` or `!=`, as Siong Thye Goh pointed out (this is because floats have a finite representation in the backend which is why this can fail unexpectedly), in this case this would also have been wrong if you were doing something similar with integers. It's a logic fault and not the wrong choice of datatype.